# yii2, how correctly cache data

Tags: php, caching, yii2

Now i have code data like this:

my const

```
    const CacheUserByUid = 'CacheUserByUid_';
    const CacheUserByUsername = 'CacheUserByUsername_';
    const CacheUserById = 'CacheUserByUsername_';
```

Get user data bu uid

```
/**
     * Get user by uid , return user data for user profile
     *
     * @param $uid
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserByUid($uid)
    {
        $result = Yii::$app->cache->getOrSet(self::CacheUserByUid . $uid, function () use ($uid) {
            $result = self::find()
                ->select([
                    'id',
                    'username',
                    'email',
                    'city',
                    'country',
                    'name',
                    'avatar',
                    'about',
                    'uid',
                ])
                ->where(['uid' => trim($uid)])
                ->one();

            if (!empty($result)) {
                $result->id = (string)$result->id;
            }

            return $result;
        });

        return $result;
    }
```

get user data by PK

```
    /**
     * @param $userId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserById($userId)
    {
        $user = Yii::$app->cache->getOrSet(self::CacheUserById . $userId, function () use ($userId) {
            return self::findOne($userId);
        });

        return $user;
    }
```

Get user by username

```
/**
     * Get user by username. Return only for user front info
     *
     * @param $username
     * @return array|\yii\db\ActiveRecord|null
     */
    public function getUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $result = Yii::$app->cache->getOrSet(self::CacheUserByUsername . $username, function () use ($username) {
            $result = self::find()->select([
                'user.id',
                'user.city',
                'user.country',
                'user.name',
                'user.avatar',
                'user.about',
                'user.username'
            ])
                ->where(['username' => $username])
                ->one();

            if (!empty($result)) {
                $result->id = (string)$result->id;
            }
        });

        return $result;
    }
```

I cached this data. And where user was update i used:

```
/**
     * @param $data
     * @param $userId
     * @return bool
     * @throws \yii\db\Exception
     */
    public function updateUser($data, $userId)
    {
        $user = $this->getUserById($userId);

        if (!empty($user)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $name) {
                if ($this->hasAttribute($key)) {
                    $user->$key = $name;
                }
            }

            $user->updatedAt = time();

            if ($user->save()) {
                //чистимо кеш
                FileCache::clearCacheByKey(self::CacheUserByUid . $user->uid);
                FileCache::clearCacheByKey(self::CacheUserByUsername . $user->username);
                FileCache::clearCacheByKey(self::CacheUserById . $user->id);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

method clearCacheByKey

```
    /**
     * @param $key
     */
    public static function clearCacheByKey($key)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->cache->exists($key)) {
            Yii::$app->cache->delete($key);
        }
    }
```

1. Am I good at using a single-user cache that caches these requests in different keys? I don't see any other way out
2. Is it ok to cache user data in FileCache?
   maybe it would be better to use something else for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, such simple queries don't need to be cached explicitly. Yii already has a query cache and your requests definitely should be already stored in the cache. The key for data in cache would be a combination of your SQL's  md5 with some connection metadata.
Just ensure that everything is [configured correctly.](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data#query-caching)

Also if you need to update cached data on some changes, make sure that you're making queries with the best for your case [cache dependency](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data#cache-dependencies). It can purge cached results by some auto condition or you can do it manually from your code(by using TagDependency)

What about FileCache it depends on traffic to your app and current infrastructure. Sometimes there is nothing criminal to store cache in files and you're always can switch to something like Redis/Memcache when your app grow big enough